# DB2 - SQL Query Insert Rows from one DatabaseA.Table to DatabaseB.Table

Tags: sql, db2

Is something like this possible in SQL/DB2?

```
INSERT INTO Prod.CD_Final (ID) 
VALUES (SELECT ID FROM Test.CD_Final);
```

I always get the error message:

> "Prod.CD_Final" is an undefined name. SQL Code: -204, SQL State: 42704
>   "Test.CD_Final" is an undefined name. SQL Code: -204, SQL State: 42704

Thanks, Stefan

Comment: I do that all the time on our DB2...are PROD and TEST your library names?  Have you tried it with / instead of . between the names?

Comment: What platform and version of DB2 are you using?

Comment: I am not allowed to change any settings on the database. It runs on AIX. The main problem is, that the Prod and the Test databases are on different servers.

Answer (score 0):

I think the two dbs need to be Federated I think. See [here](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=568387&page=82)

- also see here : [Cross-database queries with different DB names in different environments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314684/cross-database-queries-with-different-db-names-in-different-environments)

Comment: It's possible to create the synonym, but ater that I get the same Error message.